# Fragment does not refresh its content

Tags: android, listview, adapter, fragment

In the following code I have set up a fragment that shows 2 ListViews.

When the main activity call the Fragment methods:

```
 prendiListaBest
```

and

```
 prendiListaWorst
```

they call notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapters,

**therefore the lists should update with the new contents of the ArrayLists.**

But this does not happen.

Please any help and suggestion more than welcome

```
public class WorstBest extends Fragment {
    public ListView lvBest;
public ListView lvWorst;
public MyAdapter myAdap;
public MyAdapter myAdap2;
public ArrayList<Stock> best;
public ArrayList<Stock> worst;
public View v;
   @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.listaworstbest, container, false);    
        lvBest= (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listbest);
        lvWorst=(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listworst);;
        myAdap= new MyAdapter(best, getActivity());
        myAdap2= new MyAdapter(worst, getActivity());
        lvBest.setAdapter(myAdap);
        lvWorst.setAdapter(myAdap2);
        return v;              
    }

    public void prendiListaBest(ArrayList<Stock> al){
        Log.e("", "passo per prendilitsa del fragment worstbest");
        best=al;
        Log.e("", "nel fragment best è" + Integer.toString(best.size()));
        myAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }    

    public void prendiListaWorst(ArrayList<Stock> al){
        Log.e("", "passo per prendilitsa del fragment worstbest");
        worst=al;
        Log.e("", "nel fragment worst è" + Integer.toString(worst.size()));
        myAdap2.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

This is the code of my custom adapter.
I posted as requested but I apologize because it is really messy:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter   {
    ArrayList<Stock> l; 
    Activity a;

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<Stock> li, Activity ac) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    l = li;
    a=ac;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row=convertView;

    if (row==null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=a.getLayoutInflater();
    row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
    }   
    TextView tw=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    String st=l.get(position).simbolo;
    String st1=st;
    String st2=st;
    String st3=st;
    String st4=st;
    String st5=st;
    String st6=st;
    String st7=st;
    String st8=st;
    st8=st;
        if(st.length()<=7){st1=st.concat("     ");st2=st1;st3=st1;st4=st1;st5=st1;st6=st1;st7=st1;st8=st1;}
    if(st1.length()<=7){st2=st1.concat("     ");st3=st2;st4=st2;st5=st2;st6=st2;st7=st2;st8=st2;}
    if(st2.length()<=7){st3=st2.concat(" ");st4=st3;st5=st3;st6=st3;st7=st3;st8=st3;}
    if(st3.length()<=7){st4=st3.concat(" ");st5=st4;st6=st4;st7=st4;st8=st4;}
    if(st4.length()<=7){st5=st4.concat(" ");st6=st5;st7=st5;st8=st5;}
    if(st5.length()<=7){st6=st5.concat(" ");st7=st6;st8=st6;}
    if(st6.length()<=7){st7=st6.concat(" ");st8=st7;}
    if(st7.length()<=7){st8=st7.concat(" ");}

    tw.setText(st8);
    String allora=(String) tw.getText();    
    TextView tw2=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.nome);
    ///aggiungiamo numero minimo caratteri
    tw2.setText((l.get(position).nome));
    ///
    TextView tw3=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.prezzo);
    tw3.setText((l.get(position).prezzo));

    TextView tw4=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.cambiamento);
    tw4.setText((l.get(position).cambiamento).concat(" %"));

    try {
    double value = Double.parseDouble(l.get(position).cambiamento);
    if(value<0)tw4.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    if(value>0)tw4.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    TextView tw5=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.freccia);
    if(value<0)tw5.setText("▼");
    if(value>0)tw5.setText("▲");
    if(value<0)tw5.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    if(value>0)tw5.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        } catch (Exception exc) {}

    return row; 

 }

 public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return l .size();

}

 public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return l .get(position);

 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
 }
 }
```

**EDIT  EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT** **EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT **

Thank you very much, the answer makes perfectly sense.**

But I do not understand why the same Adapter works fine with the following fragment; I explain:
the following "listafragment" fragment has a similar logic, it uses the

```
 prendiLista
```

method to retrieve the latest version of the

```
 ListArray lt
```

exactly the same way it is done in the previous "WorstBest" fragment.
But in this case when

```
    public void prendiLista(ArrayList<Stock> al){
        lt=al;
         myAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**the view is updated !!!**

**Please what is the difference??? :-)**

**IN MY UNDERSTANDING THE CALL TO notifyDataSetChanged() WAS ENOUGH TO UPDATE THE VIEW !!**

Thanks a lot anyway! (I will accept answer tomorrow morning).

```
 public class listafragment extends Fragment {
    public ListView lv;
    public MyAdapter myAdap;
    public ArrayList<Stock> lt;
    public View v;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.lista, container, false);    
        lv= (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        if(lv==null){Log.e("","nel fragment la lista è nulla");}
         if(lv!=null){Log.e("","nel fragment la lista NON è nulla");} 
         myAdap= new MyAdapter(lt, getActivity()); 
         lv.setAdapter(myAdap);             
        return v;
    }

    public void prendiLista(ArrayList<Stock> al){
        Log.e("", "passo per prendilitsa del fragment");
        lt=al;
        if(myAdap==null){Log.e("","nel prendilista del fragment myadapt è     nullo");};
        myAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }                 
       public void addToFavorites(int pos){
         Quotes.addToFavorites(pos);

     }

     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        lt=Quotes.dammi();
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have custom adapters. Can you please post the code of those classes? Perhaps you are not implementing notifyDataSetChanged correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> therefore the lists should update with the new contents of the ArrayLists.

Unfortunately no. When your app first runs `l` and `best` both reference the same data. You have this set up.

```
Fragment:
    best ---\
            |
            |--- <the initial data>
Adapter:    |
    l ------/
```

But after you call `best=al`, you have:

```
Fragment:
    best ------- <the new data>

Adapter:    
    l ---------- <the initial data>
```

So you never update the reference in your Adapter. Either add a new method to your custom Adapter to change `l` *or* use `l` itself since you didn't declare it as `private`:

```
public void prendiListaBest(ArrayList<Stock> al){
    myAdap.l=al;
    myAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: answer is correct but a more encapsulated way would be to use a public method of the adapter to refill its internal list : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12662994/693752

Comment: I agree and suggested the same technique in my answer. I am hoping this code demonstrates how exposed `l` is, but I felt the answer was long enough already...

Comment: @Sam Thanks a lot! But please would you mind having a look at my edits, I have some perplexities,although your answer makes perfectly sense? (I will accept the answer tomorrow morning anyway). Thanks Again.

Comment: @pietmau That is confusing. Are you changing `Quotes.dammi()` somewhere else?

Comment: @Sam Thanks Sam. I am invoking the main Activity method `lt=Quotes.dammi()` to retrieve the data set at the beginning (it is in onCreate...) after that, when the dataset changes the main activity calls `prendiLista(ArrayList<Stock> al)` to notify that the data are changed. And it works... thanks again

Comment: can any one check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148618/listview-not-refreshing-after-click-on-button