# When items are redrawn after invoking `invalidateViews()`

Tags: java, android, c, adapter, android-arrayadapter

When are the items redrawn after invoking `invalidateViews()` ?

I ask because i try to refresh `listItems` after a bg-thread notify an image rsc was downloaded.

But nothing is updated. Only after exiting and re-entering the new icons are drawn.

I have an activity with `adapter` of type `SettingValueAdapter extends BaseAdapter`

it has a member:

`private SettingsValue[] values;`

it has two interesting methods:

```
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

                AddressItem ai= (AddressItem)getItem(position);
                DriveToNativeManager dnm = DriveToNativeManager.getInstance();


                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = li.inflate(R.layout.address_item, null);
                }

                view.setTag(R.id.addressItem,ai);
                view.setTag(position);
                view.findViewById(R.id.fullAddressItemCol).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                view.findViewById(R.id.addressItemTouch).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                view.findViewById(R.id.addressItemImage).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (ai != null) {
                ...
    }
                    view.findViewById(R.id.addressItemIconLayout).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Drawable icon = ResManager.GetSkinDrawable(ai.getIcon() + ".bin");
                    ((ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.addressItemIcon)).setImageDrawable(icon);

                  ..
                    }
}


        public void refreshListIcons()  {


    //      NativeManager nativeManager = AppService.getNativeManager();
    //      SettingsValue[] values = new SettingsValue[categories.length];
    //      for (int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    //          values[i] = new SettingsValue(categories[i].value, nativeManager.getLanguageString(categories[i].displayString), false);
    //          values[i].icon = ResManager.GetSkinDrawable(categories[i].iconName + ".bin");
    //      }
    //      adapter.setValues(values);


            this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();         
                }
            });


    }
```

I attach a callback to the bg-thread (c language) image downloading process.

The callback switches to the ui-thread and calls this `refreshList`:

```
public void refreshSearchIconsOnSearchActivity() {

        Runnable refreshViewEvent = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Activity currentActivity = AppService.getActiveActivity();

                if (currentActivity instanceof SearchActivity) {

                    Log.d("w", "refreshSearchIconsOnSearchActivity callback running in thread "
                                    + Thread.currentThread().getId() );
                    //results list
                    ((SearchActivity) currentActivity).refreshList();

                }
            }
        };
        AppService.Post(refreshViewEvent);
    }
```

However, the images are done downloading and are not refreshed on the activity.

They are refreshed only when I leave an re-enter the activity.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is this a `C` question?

Comment: the bg-thread is in c. I have thought that might be a clue

Comment: Check the following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903758/android-how-to-refresh-listview-contents

Comment: I have seen this before. I don't need to change the list items. The image url doesn't change. I want it to redraw, as now the resource is downloaded.

Comment: Is `refreshList` in the second code block a typo for `refreshListIcons`?

Answer (score 4):

InvalidateViews just causes the listView to redraw itself.  It will not call getView to do so, it just resets the current ones on screen-  basically it just does

```
for(View child: getChildren()){
    child.invalidate();
}
```

If you want to update the list, call notifyDataSetChanged on the adaptor.

Comment: I have tried this as well (see my `refreshList()` method). But nothing happens

Comment: Are you updating whatever array that holds the data used by getItem(position)?

Comment: Also, is your ResManager.GetSkinDrawable updating the value returned after the download, or is it maybe stuck returning some default (or null)?