# How to update a ListView from a MultiChoiceAdapter library?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm trying to implement [this example](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter/tree/master/samples/stock/src/com/manuelpeinado/multichoiceadapter/samples/stock/complexitemlayoutsample) from [this MultiChoiceAdapter](https://github.com/ManuelPeinado/MultiChoiceAdapter) library.

It looks perfect so far. The only thing that I changed is the `ListView` height and added a `Button` after such `ListView`.

[image]

Now, my idea with that `Button` is to update the adapter. For that, I created the following method:

```
private void updateData(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4");
    adapter = null;
    adapter = new ComplexItemLayoutAdapter(savedInstanceState, items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

At the end, it did not work. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12662994/1188208) answer, but it did not work because this example does not extend [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html).

What can I do to update this kind of adapter?

Many thanks.

Comment: why do you set adapter to null and make a new instance?

Comment: Because I'm not sure how to update it. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created one method in `ComplexItemLayoutAdapter` named `setData(List<String> items)` and set these items to existing data.

And change your method implementation

```
    private void updateData(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4");
        adapter = null;
        adapter = new ComplexItemLayoutAdapter(savedInstanceState, items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

to

```
    private void updateData(){
        List<String> items = Arrays.asList("Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4");
        adapter.setData(items);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: I feel stupid. I noticed that I was using a different `adapter` than `ComplexItemLayoutAdapter` in the example. How dumb that I did not see it before. Thanks!