# android listview not showing new added items.if i do keyboard off or on with back key list refreshed

Tags: android, listview, lis

when i hide keyboard with back key on android list is fully working and there is new items that i add. i want to refresh list without using back key to hide keyboard.
my code is :

```
lv=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
strArr=new ArrayList<String>();
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getApplicationContext() , R.layout.custom_list , strArr);

lv.setAdapter(adapter);

while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ){
    strArr.add(line);
}

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903758/android-how-to-refresh-listview-contents?rq=1

Comment: when i remove this line it works without back button to hide keyboard "adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();"

Comment: lv.invalidateViews();

Answer (score 0):

You are stuck in the loop until you click the back button. Try:

```
while( ( line = br.readLine() ) != null ){
   strArr.add(line);
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```